# Insert sequential number in XML node using R

Tags: r, xml

I have an xml file like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
  <row> 
    <ID>49414</ID>
    <Check>1</Check>
    <Date>27/3/2019 0:00:00</Date>
  </row>
  <row>
    <ID>49643</ID>
    <Check>1</Check>
    <Date>27/3/2019 0:00:00</Date>
  </row>

…
```

In the `row` nodes I need an additional identifier based on the sequential number, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
  <row itemID="1"> 
    <ID>49414</ID>
    <Check>1</Check>
    <Date>27/3/2019 0:00:00</Date>
  </row>
  <row itemID="2">
    <ID>49643</ID>
    <Check>1</Check>
    <Date>27/3/2019 0:00:00</Date>
  </row>
…
```

Is there any straight way to perform this task using R?
Thanks in advance.

**What I have tried**

I have checked the answers to this question, [Editing XML files in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547659/editing-xml-files-in-r) but when I apply `xpathApply` I don't get the empty values of `row`, but the collapsed values of the sibling nodes:

```
> x<-xmlParse('mydata.xml')
> xmlValue(xpathApply(x,"//row")[[1]])
[1] "49414127/3/2019 0:00:00"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)

x <- read_xml('mydata.xml')

# the following modifies nodes in x
x %>%
  xml_find_all('./row') %>%
  xml_set_attr('itemID', seq_along(.)) 

x %>%
  write_xml('mydata2.xml')
```

Then "mydata2.xml" contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
  <row itemID="1">
    <ID>49414</ID>
    <Check>1</Check>
    <Date>27/3/2019 0:00:00</Date>
  </row>
  <row itemID="2">
    <ID>49643</ID>
    <Check>1</Check>
    <Date>27/3/2019 0:00:00</Date>
  </row>
</document>
```